# ArcGIS Script Tool Input Parameters giving Error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5, python-script-tool

I am using Desktop 10.5.1

I have a python script, works great when I copy/paste into the ArcMap terminal and replace the `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` function with a hard-coded string variable.

However when I put this script as a script tool inside a toolbox I get errors for the input values.

the code is below for the script tool.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

structures = arcpy.GetParameter[0]
Prim_Conductor = arcpy.GetParameter[1]
TableOutput = arcpy.GetParameter[2]
PrimConductor_FL = "Primary_Conductor FL"
structures_FL = "structures_lyr"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(structures, structures_FL)

whereSQL = """ Damage_Cat = 'Major Damage' OR Damage_Cat = 'Minor Damage' """

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(structures_FL, "NEW_SELECTION", whereSQL)

bufferOutput = r"\\path\to\shapefile.shp"
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(structures_FL, bufferOutput,"20 Feet", line_side="FULL", line_end_type="ROUND", dissolve_option="NONE", dissolve_field="", method="PLANAR")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(structures_FL, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Prim_Conductor, PrimConductor_FL)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(PrimConductor_FL, "INTERSECT", bufferOutput)


arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(PrimConductor_FL, TableOutput, "NAME")
```

Parameter data types in the tool properties are:

- [0]: Feature Class (it is a SDE featureclass)
- [1]: Feature Class (SDE Feature Class)
- [2]: File (output direction)- output for excel file.

The error I see is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\Emergency Data\Electric V-Look Up\Script Tool\Script.py", line 7, in <module>
    structures = arcpy.GetParameter[0]
TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Failed to execute (Script).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to "get" an item (sort of like from an array or list) because of the brackets to mark the parameter number - the function takes the index for each parameter in () parentheses.  Also, GetParameter() returns an object (instead of a string value to input into geoprocesses, like you have).

Simple fix:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

structures = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Prim_Conductor = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
TableOutput = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
```

Comment: ahh this works if I open the directory folder and navigate to the FC, but it wont let em drag and drop it in the parameter box. Says Invalid...?

Comment: Yup that's an annoying thing - when the FC draws in Arc it's creating a layer (in memory) - go into the Script Properties window and change that parameter type to Layer from the drop-down, and it should work as intended.